# Automate iOS webkit within application

Tags: ios, swift, selenium, automation, webkit

I am currently developing an ios app. One of the features in the app requires some WebKit automation. I am looking to do something similar to what selenium does; I want to input text into a textfield using its ID or Xpath and than press a button using its ID or Xpath.

Example: Inputting text into google search bar on google.com, and than clicking search programmatically.

I have done the above in selenium (Java). Although I am looking for a way to do this on ios (using swift). Is there anyway I can do this natively? Or is there a cocoapod I can use to do this? If not, would it be viable to use swift to run a javascript file to do this?

I am also aware of a cocoapod called WKZombie, it does exactly what I need it to although its documentation is fairly confusing and it is a headless browser (I want the user to see what is happening, so that doesn't work, although I could grab the HTML and display it if there is no other way to do this). Also I don't think appium will work because I want this to work in the standalone app.

(Also, this is my first post so I apologize for any improper improper formatting or anything like that)

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to auto-navigate through multiple pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate with the page loaded in a `WKWebView` view via JavaScript:

- The simplest way is to use `evaluateJavaScript(_, completionHandler)` which allows you to inject code, e.g. to change the DOM, trigger actions, etc.
- Or, you can inject a user script (`WKUserScript`) when creating the web view which can call back to your Swift code, which requires more setup but also is more powerful.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I see how to run evaluateJavaScript(_, completionHandler) on one page, but how would you run this to automate credentialed navigation of multiple pages?

Comment: All your pages most likely live inside the same webview. You can determine based on the current URL which script to inject.

Answer (score 0):

To host a browser in your application the class you need to use is [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) (replaces the older UIWebView). The [evaluateJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) method can of WKWebView can be used to inject JS into the WKWebView instance. You can include the Textbox filling, button clicking magic into the JS that you are injecting.